# C++ Durand-Kerner root finding algorithm crashes with GMP, but not with long double

Tags: c++, algorithm, gmp

I am trying a root-finding algorithm based on [Durand-Kerner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durand%E2%80%93Kerner_method) and I need it for polynomials of orders maybe up to 50, with coefficients that go beyond `long double` or `long long`, so I am trying (for the 1st time) [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Now, I made this program as a test, which is why the `main()` is as it is (plus I am not an advanced programmer), and it works if I don't involve GMP, so I think it's something in my implementation that makes it crash. With Codeblock's debugger it points to some lines inside `gmpxx.h` and at the function `f()`, the line with the `sum +=`.

Here's the code, minus the polynomial coefficient generation (here a simple loop):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>   // std::vector
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>  // std::setprecision
#include <gmpxx.h>

typedef std::complex<mpf_class> cplx;

// x!
mpz_class fact(const unsigned int &x)
{
    mpz_class z {1};
    for (unsigned int i=1; i<=x; ++i)
        z *= i;
    return z;
}

// 2^n
mpz_class pwr2(const unsigned int &n)
{
    mpz_class z {1};
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        z *= 2;
    return (n == 0 ? 1 : z);
}

void bessel(std::vector<mpz_class> &a, const unsigned int &N)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<=N; ++i)
        a[i] = fact(N + i) / fact(N - i) / fact(i) / pwr2(i);
    //return *a;
}

// Definition for f(x), will be called for every iteration
cplx f(const std::vector<mpz_class> &coeff, const cplx &xterm)
{
    cplx sum {0, 0};
    cplx factor {1, 0};
    for (unsigned int k=coeff.size(); k>=0; --k)
    {
        sum += static_cast<cplx>(coeff[k]) * factor;
        factor *= xterm;
        std::cout<<sum<<'\n';
    }
    return sum;
}

// Denominator, product of differences. root is the current root's value
cplx prod(const std::vector<cplx> &roots, const cplx &root)
{
    cplx product {1.0, 0};
    for (unsigned int k=0; k<roots.size(); ++k)
    {
        // Skip if an element of the matrix == current root
        if (roots[k] == root)
            product = product;
        else
            product *= root - roots[k];
    }
    return product;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "N=";
    unsigned int N;
    double eps {1e-10}; // relative error
    std::cin >> N;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(16);

    // Declaring arrays for coefficients, initial and final roots
    unsigned int arraySize {N + 1};
    std::vector<mpz_class> coeffs;
    std::vector<cplx> initial;
    std::vector<cplx> roots;
    coeffs.resize(arraySize);
    initial.resize(arraySize);
    roots.resize(arraySize);
    // Keep track of number and maximum numbers of iterations.
    unsigned int maxIter {200};
    unsigned int iters {0};

    for (unsigned int k=0; k<arraySize; ++k)
    {
        coeffs[k] = k+1;
        std::cout << coeffs[k] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Initialize the seed roots
    for (unsigned int k=0; k<N; ++k)
        initial[k] = pow(cplx(0.6, 0.8), k);
    // Temporary array to hold next iteration's values
    bool delta[N];
    mpf_class tmp[N];
    while (iters <= maxIter)
    {
        for (unsigned int k=0; k<N; ++k)
        {
            roots[k] = initial[k] - f(coeffs, initial[k]) / prod(initial, initial[k]);
        }
        // Calculate the abs() average of the temporary roots
        bool test {1};
        for (unsigned int k=0; k<N; ++k)
        {
            tmp[k] = fabs(initial[k] - roots[k]);
            delta[k] = tmp[k] <= eps;
            test *= delta[k];
            //test *= fabs(initial[k] - roots[k]) <= eps;
            //std::cout << tmp[k] << " ";
        }
        //std::cout << '\n';
        // Check if eps has been reached
        if (test)
            break;
        // if not, initial roots take current roots' value
        for (unsigned int k=0; k<N; ++k)
            initial[k] = roots[k];
        ++iters;
    }
    /// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    for (unsigned short k=0; k<N; ++k)
        std::cout << tmp[k] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    for (unsigned short k=0; k<N; ++k)
        std::cout << initial[k] << "\n";
    std::cout << iters << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The `std::cout` line in the `f()` function gets printed only if it's inside the loop, else it won't, so the error must have some connection, but I'm afraid it goes over my head. Can someone help me with the error? What gets me is that the whole algorithm works just fine with standard types.

---

Here's the callstack:

```
#0 0x7ffff7951e00   __gmpf_set_z() (/usr/lib/libgmp.so.10:??)
#1 0x404562 __gmp_set_expr<__mpz_struct [1]>(f=0x7fffffffe2f0, expr=...) (/usr/include/gmpxx.h:2114)
#2 0x403661 __gmp_expr<__mpf_struct [1], __mpf_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>(this=0x7fffffffe2f0, expr=...) (/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1844)
#3 0x401d5c f(coeff=std::vector of length 5, capacity 5 = {...}, xterm=...) (/home/xxx/Documents/cpp/Durand_Kerner_gmp/main.cpp:51)
#4 0x40250f main() (/home/xxx/Documents/cpp/Durand_Kerner_gmp/main.cpp:112)
```

The program starts showing `N=`, input 4, for example.

Comment: Can you post the call stack after it has crashed? A screenshot would do. Also post the line of code calling the crashed function, and the arguments you pass to it (their values as the debugger shows them).

Comment: @sashoalm I don't really understand the 2nd part, but `f()` is called inside `main()`, at `roots[k] = initial[k] - ...`, and the debugger points inside the definition of `f()`, at `sum += static_cast...`. The values shown by the debugger are of mixed sort, I have to keep on expanding every line for every value, it goes something like `coeff > [0] > mp > [0]` and there are `_mp_alloc`, `_mp_size` and `_mp_d`.

Comment: "warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true" first fix all the warnings? And don't use unsigned types.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I must have missed that between the errors. As soon as I replaced all `unsigned` it didn't crash anymore. There are wrong results, but that's my doing now. Thank you for the solution. If you'd post this as an answer, I'll mark it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gcc can point out one important issue:

```
a.cc: In function ‘cplx f(const std::vector<__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]> >&, const cplx&)’:
a.cc:40:40: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Wtype-limits]
     for (unsigned int k=coeff.size(); k>=0; --k)
                                       ~^~~
```

Unsigned types should be avoided, unless you are creating your own bigint type (or possibly using a bitfield) and know what you are doing.

Comment: I am using big ints, longer than `long long`, but GMP should more than cover that. At any rate, it's working now, though not for high order polynomials, but that's another question if I don't fix it.